# How to set image received from a web service as ImagePaint in Blackberry 10.1?

Tags: qt, blackberry, qml, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

I am populating a QVariantMap with JSON data which I'm getting from a web service. This data contains, among other things, URL for images. Now I want to use these images as ImagePaint in my qml file, but in Blackberry OS 10.1, setting the `imageSource` to the URL doesn't load the image.

What is the way around this problem? Thanks.

Comment: You will need to download and set it on your own. [Check this](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Native-Development/Loading-image-from-URL/td-p/1717927) and [official git](https://github.com/blackberry/Cascades-Samples/tree/master/tldr)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a WebView to display your image like the following:

```
Webview {
    url: "link/to/your/image"
}
```